# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined while trying to loop through json array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I keep getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined 
I did a console.log and it returned the array. example:

```
[
  {
    "comment_id":"702542",
    "parcel_id":"166865",
    "user_id":"10034",
    "comment":"2014+ LCV RESPONSE - FINAL LETTER (07-JAN-2014) RECEIVED 01\/13\/2014 COMPLETED AS PRIMARY RESIDENCE - LEGAL CLASS NOT UPDATED.",
    "date_created":"2014-01-30 01:00:00"
  }
]
```

I can't seem to get it to populate the table in the jquery dialog box when the user clicks on the view comments button.

Here's the jquery code: **updated**

```
    $('#ViewComments').click(function() {
        $("#InsertComment").focus();
        //view/add comments dialog
        $( "#CommentsDialog" ).dialog({
            height:320,
            width: 500,
            modal:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            buttons: [ { text: "Close", click: function() { $(this).dialog( "close" ); } } ]
        });
        var parcel_id = $('#ParcelId').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "classes/get-comments.php?parcel_id=" + parcel_id,
            type: "GET",
            data: { parcel_id : parcel_id },
            error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(comments){
                //do stuff here on success
                //console.log(comments);
                for(var i=0; i < comments.length; i++){
                    var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + comments[0].date_created + "</td><td style=\"text-align:right;\">" + comments[0].user_id + "</td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\">" + comments[0].comment + "</td>");
                    $('#CommentResults').append(tr);
                    //console.log(tr);
                }
            }
        });
    });//end view comments click function
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="CommentsDialog" title="Comments">
        <div style="width:98%;height:75%; margin-bottom:5px; background-color: #fff; padding:5px;" id="Comments" name="Comments">
            <table id="CommentResults" name="CommentResults"></table>               
        </div>
        <input type="text" style="width:65%;margin-top:5px;" id="InsertComment" /> <input type="button" id="AddComment" value="Add Comment" class="floatRight" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: The error you are getting doesn't match your code... did you leave something out? You never tried to reference a `create` property.

Comment: The php code? I did a console.log in the success function and it returned the full array.

Comment: No, your javascript code. You never used a create property, therefore that error couldn't have possibly been caused by the code you displayed in your question.

Comment: I did, sorry, I forgot the rest of the click function.

Comment: hmm... i still don't see `somethingthatisntdefined.create()`

Comment: your guess is as good as mine because i didnt do anything with `.create`. the only thing i'm trying to create is the table rows for the information returned. I have been searching for an answer for 2 days now... I am completely stuck :(

Comment: The error message in your console should be accompanied by a stack trace(often times hidden behind a down arrow, or sitting on the right side of the console). Can you include that in your question?

Comment: @KevinB i forgot to put the `dataType: "json"` property in >.>

Comment: I still don't see why that would have caused the error you mentioned.

Comment: I don't know either but it works now, so weird :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your ajax request, add :

```
dataType: "json"
```

Comment: Yet another reason why returning a proper Content-Type header from your server is so important.